# Drained battery; imminent explosion?

Tags: battery, battery-charger

What would happens when if a car battery is drained of all its fluid and then hooked up to a 12v battery charger. It's a long story I did it to my car battery accidentally for about a minute. What could have happened if I had left it on to charge for longer?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 7):

In a word: nothing.

If a battery is completely dry, or has a lack of electrolyte which doesn't contact the bottom of the charge plates, then nothing will happen. Even if one cell of a 6-cell battery (typical lead-acid 12vdc battery) is dry, nothing would happen. The reason is, the electrolyte (sulfuric acid) allows connectivity between plates. If there is no electrolyte, there is no connectivity. It's like a wire with an open circuit ... it doesn't work. You need to have the electrical circuit within the battery to have a clear path between posts. If it it isn't there, no electrons will flow, and therefore nothing happens.

Comment: If the “padding” or support beneath the plates is still moist then you can get an appreciable voltage but no significant power.

Comment: @SolarMike - Agree with you. I guess in this case it all depends on the OP's definition of "drained".  I'm taking them at their word and the common meaning of the term.